# Rasperry Pi - Control circuit through website

Tags: web, raspberry-pi3

I got my Raspberry Pi 3 quite recently and have made some basic projects. I'm looking for a method to create a website (on my laptop) and control my raspberry pi through that - well, more just a circuit attached to it. Would that be possible? If so, how would I approach it?

Comment: I think there are already good tutorials online...

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the language you want to use for the project, you will want to find a gpio library to control the GPIO pins. You would then want to wrap the calls in a webserver. Some examples of the libraries:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/RPi.GPIO
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/pi-gpio
- http://wiringpi.com/

Comment: Alright thanks, I'll look into it a lot more. I suppose npmjs is a javascript library?

Comment: I've done some work with npmjs, I don't get how I'm supposed to use it? My aim is to run the GPIO pins wirelessly through a website.

Comment: npmjs.com is a package repository. That library is for the nodejs language. You might want to back up a bit and read a tutorial on creating and running python programs on the raspberry pi, then look into using the library in the first link.

Comment: I've made (and run) python programs with it, using RPi - I would just really like to use my circuits remotely through a website